# How to put multiple shapes on the same graph GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am creating a UI in GUIDE, and I am wondering how does one put multiple 2 dimensional polygons on the same axes. When I try to do it, it either overwrites the old one, or creates a new window. I already have axes (handles.axes1) in my code, but that is not working. How do I get multiple shapes in the same plot?

Comment: have you tried `hold on`

Comment: I did not know about this feature. Thank you for that. It does only work with fill shapes, but that is sufficient for me. That pretty much solves my question.